# Is it possible to have Google Cloud Kubernetes cluster in the free tier?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, containers

Looking over the [Free Tier characteristics](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier) for Google Cloud, it states that -

- VM instances must be in a region like **us-west1**
- VM machine types must be **f1-micro**

So, to tie that together I created the following shell command to create a Kubernetes cluster -

```
gcloud container clusters create free-cluster-1 -m f1-micro --region us-west1
```

Which attempts to create a cluster named free-cluster-1 with the free tier machine type, and in the free tier region.

However, I get back this error message when running that command -

```
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.create) ResponseError: code=400, message=Node pools of f1-micro machines are not supported due to insufficient memory.
```

Does this mean that you simply can't create Kubernetes clusters in the free tier for Google Cloud? Or is there another way around this limitation?

Comment: No, you can't. But you can with IBM Cloud (if it's only the K8S part that is important for you. If it's the Google Cloud ecosystem... sorry!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you're not able to create GKE cluster based on `f1-micro` shared-core machine type.

Have a look at the documentation [Choosing a minimum CPU platform](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/min-cpu-platform) section [Limitations](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/min-cpu-platform#limitations):

> Minimum CPU platform cannot be used with shared core machine types,
> such as `g1-small`.

So, because `f1-micro` [shared-core machine type](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#n1_shared-core_machine_types) has even less resources than `g1-small` the error you've got should be expected.

In addition, have a look at the error message:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.create) ResponseError: code=400, message=Node pools of f1-micro machines are not supported due to insufficient memory.
```

it's clearly states that "f1-micro machines are not supported due to insufficient memory".